# Drag and Drop between Instances of the same application. (Winforms)

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I have an application with a ListView where i drop some files from the Explorer. The Object is seen as FileDrop and thus, i can populate the ListView with the name, extension and full path of all the items i drop inside. The problem comes when i drag a ListView item from the first app to the ListView at the second instance of the same app. The item is passed as System.__ComObject, not as Text as i supposed.

How (and where) could i drag an item between those two different ListViews, each one at their own app, passing it like a FileDrop or plain text?

I read a lot about serialize, and some others examples, but all seems not very friendly to self teach...

```
 private void Playlist_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {

        Playlist.DoDragDrop(Playlist.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text, DragDropEffects.Move);

    }
```

Some more code:

```
private void Playlist_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) || e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) { this.Externo = true; }
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) { this.Externo = false; }

            Point cp = Playlist.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            ListViewItem hoverItem = Playlist.GetItemAt(cp.X, cp.Y);


            if (hoverItem == null)
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                return;
            }

            foreach (ListViewItem moveItem in Playlist.SelectedItems)
            {

                if (moveItem.Index == hoverItem.Index)
                {
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
                    hoverItem.EnsureVisible();

                    return;
                }
            }
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            hoverItem.EnsureVisible();
        }

    }
```

The - external or text - 'if' statement is just to say whether the drag comes from inside the ListView (so it will reorder the ListView Items) or comes from the Explorer, (so it will Add the item to the hovered position).

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. If i drop that to a valid drag drop app like Textedit, i get the text passed there. But my question is related to how to drag drop a list view item to any other app (casted, serialized... whatever) in a different type than System.__ComObject. Thanks.